# MacPorts selfupdate error: set_max_open_files: setrlimit failed: invalid argument

Tags: macports

I have recently re-installed MacPorts from the High Sierra install package. When for example run `port selfupdate` (or any other command) I get the following error:

```
set_max_open_files: setrlimit failed: invalid argument
    while executing
"set_max_open_files"
    (procedure "mportinit" line 41)
    invoked from within
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, set_max_open_files: setrlimit failed: invalid argument
```

Running in `sudo` everything works properly but if I recall correctly this was not necessary before I re-installed. I'm on OSX 10.13.3. I found no earlier reference to this problem and I was wondering if someone knows the reason for this?

Comment: I had the same problem with version 2.5.4 on Mojave 10.14.5 and I fixed it by upgrading to 10.14.6.  AFAIK, sudo has always been required for `selfupdate` or most other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [page](https://www.sudo.ws/stable.html#1.8.30), you can update `sudo` to latest version `1.8.30`.